# I have set content security policy inside the meta tag in html but still the policy is not followed

Tags: html, content-security-policy

I have set up the Content Security Policy inside the meta tag in html

```
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"  content="frame-src http://localhost:35637/" /> >
        <title>User Input</title>
```

Still when I run the code and see the developers tool I am getting

> Refused to frame 'http://localhost:35637/' because it violates the
> following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self'".

Why is it not able to detect the "frame-src http://localhost:35637/" and showing "frame-src 'self' "

Comment: You will need to define CSP as part of the HTTP headers, not HTML header...

Comment: @f_puras
I have my html code which contains a form and the action method of form has post method which calls 'http://localhost:35637/'. How to set up http headers in front end

Comment: It is not part of the front-end, but usually belongs to the webserver configuration, i.e. Apache, IIS or nginx, depending on what you use. There is no point in placing the directives in the HTML itself, because in case of an XSS attack, they could be manipulated as well.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that the there is a Content-Security-Policy set with the directive "frame-src 'self'" on your page. This is most likely set as a response header. You are adding another policy, and that can only make the total enforced policy stricter. You will need to identify how the existing policy is set and modify or remove it.